# ChromeOptions() import is not working in python selenium syntax error?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to python and I tried to disable the Chrome extensions using selenium in python.
By using the following lines

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

But first I tried to import the chromeOptions with the following import statement

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

I also tried this , but with no result.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options
```

So I looked up on the internet and everyone used the import statements like this?
And it keeps throwing error and says that the following import is not used?
When I try to used the ChromeOption() it doesn't work but it immediately gave me errors and said that it isn't imported. Meanwhile I have the chrome option line in my code.
Any help would be appreciated 
Thank you

Comment: whats your error?

Comment: @Wonka After I put the import statement in my code I tried to use the ChromeOption(), but it immediately gave me errors and said that it isn't imported.

Comment: I dont have any import for options, just "from selenium import webdriver" and just "options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem with the code is the line:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

To fix this you can simply start by importing Options() 
for the imports you can either do it like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

and then call

```
chrome_options = Options()
```

or if you import :

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options
```

then you need to call

```
chrome_options = options.Options()
```

once you initiated chrome_options, then you can write the rest of your code:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I hope this helped, if you still encounter errors do not hesitate to share the error messages here.

Answer (score 0):

```
# selenium 4

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).